# GetMethod from a current class returns null

Tags: c#, linq, generics, methods

I have public static class `MyClass` where I have 2 method overloads (basically method overload accepts `MyType1` and another overload accepts `MyType2`, these types are inherited from `MyTypeBase`).

And I'm calling one of overloads from third method (`MyPrivateStaticMethod()`), which accepts generics (`where TArgs : MyTypeBase`), so that I can have one method (`MyPrivateStaticMethod()`) to handle all the types that inherit same base type.

```
// Get Method
var myPrivateStaticMethod =
    typeof(MyClass)
    .GetMethod(
        "MyPrivateStaticMethod",
        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
        null,
        new Type[]
        {
            typeof(TArgs),
        },
        null
    );

if (myPrivateStaticMethod == null)
{
    // Handle not overloaded method
}

// Trigger method with needed type
myPrivateStaticMethod.Invoke(
    null, 
    new object[] 
    {
        someVar1, // Let's say this is int
        somevar2  // And this is MyType1 or MyType2, 
                  // depending on what type we do have there
});
```

The problem is that I can't find method by so. On the other hand if I queue by LINQ: `(...).GetMethods(...).Where(x => x.Name == "MyMethodNameIWantToFind").FirstOrDefault();` 
it does find method, 
but problem is it doesn't find overload I need

(with right type - in my case `MyType1` or `MyType2`, it takes first method it finds (`MyType1`), because I declare this overload earlier than second, this is not useful when I have passed `MyType2` in runtime to that method).

Problem: I need to find private static method with multiple parameters in signature inside of current class. Have I missed something inside my .GetMethod() use?

Comment: You're looking for the method that takes one parameter of type `TArgs` but then you're invoking it with two parameters ( `someVar1` and `someVar2` ). If they use two parameters then specify both of them.

Comment: Side note: No need for `Where(...).FirstOrDefault()`, `FirstOrDefault(...)` will work just fine.

Comment: you should use `new Type[] {typeOfFirstArg, typeof(TArgs)}` because right now you're looking for a method that takes a single parameter of type `TArgs` and there is no such method thus you get `null`

Comment: @m.rogalski thanks, this actually has helped me!

Comment: @PavelSanatov Instead of update just post an answer with updated and working code, then accept it for the future visitors.

Comment: BTW, There is a library called [ReflectionMagic](https://github.com/davidebbo/ReflectionMagic) that can take all this pain away: `this.AsDynamic().MyPrivateStaticMethod(someVar1,someVar2)`

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with my  `new Type[] {...}` array inside of `.GetMethod()`. There was only one type defined instead of my count of object types I'm passing to `MyPrivateStaticMethod()` method.